# Putting Listview Under Buttons Xamarin/Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I currently have an axml file and I want to put a series of 3 buttons with a listview underneath it.

The problem I currently have is that the lsitview is overlapping the buttons.

My current code is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerlayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bDone"
            android:text="Done"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bCancel"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bSelAll"
            android:text="Select All"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

How this looks can be seen here (when the listview populates the rows in the list overlap the buttons).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3P0h.png

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the linear layout that holds the buttons and the listview are both in a relative layout. Views in relative layout can overlap, and in your case you are not setting the listview to be aligned underneath the linear layout that holds your buttons.

**Solution 1:**

Make the RelativeLayout a LinearLayout.

**Solution 2:**

add this to the listview: `android:layout_below="@+id/headerlayout"`

You should read about the specific android layouts.